# How to select only specific defines in a SWIG interface?

Tags: python, c, header-files, swig

i have a C header file with many defines for registers, and in my Python SWIG interface i only want to expose a few. My C header looks like this (just with many more defines):

```
#define REG_1 0x0001
#define REG_2 0x0002
#define REG_3 0x0003
```

Let's say in my generated Python module if I want to have all defines accessible, I can just do:

```
%module myheader
%{
#include myheader.h
%}

%include myheader.h
```

But what if I only want to have REG_1 accessible/wrapped? I tried something like:

```
%module myheader
%{
#include myheader.h
%}

%constant REG_1;
```

But it didn't work. Checked the documentation, still clueless unfortunately. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [advanced renaming](https://swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_advanced_renaming) support of SWIG.

Given the demo header file (defs.h):

```
#define WRAP_ME_1 1
#define WRAP_ME_2 2

#define IGNORE_ME_1 1
#define IGNORE_ME_2 2
```

An interface written like:

```
%module test

%ignore "";
%rename("%s", regexmatch$name="^WRAP_ME") "";
%include "defs.h"
```

Will wrap only things which start with 'WRAP_ME' (by regex).

Likewise:

```
%module test

%rename("$ignore", regexmatch$name="^IGNORE_ME") "";    
%include "defs.h"
```

Will wrap all except those beginning with 'IGNORE_ME'.

There are flavours of this you can employ, outlined in the linked docs, but that's the general gist of pattern matching to selectively wrap things.

Comment: Thanks, i saw your answer a bit late, but thats a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to be repetitive and declare exactly what you want to expose:

```
%module myheader
%{
#include myheader.h
%}

#define REG_1 0x0001
```